# How to change ItemsSource if the ObservableCollection in another class?

Tags: c#, list, telerik, observablecollection, itemssource

I want to change my `ItemsSource` but i set the ObservableCollection in another class. How can i `Add` something to my `ItemsSource` if the ObservableCollection isn't there?

in **Edit** window :

```
private void manageLayout_Click(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        scheduleDetail = assetListClass.GetScheduleDetail(xmlScheduleDetail);
        ObservableCollection<LibraryData> scheduleDetailOC = new ObservableCollection<LibraryData>(scheduleDetail);
        ManageLayout manageLayoutWin = new ManageLayout();
        this.Close();
        manageLayoutWin.Show();
        manageLayoutWin.ManageLayout_GridView.ItemsSource = scheduleDetailOC;
        ...
     }
```

if it's in the same class i can just use this code :

```
scheduleDetailOC.Add(abc);
```

but what if it's in another class? What should i do in **ManageLayout** window to change the ItemsSource? i tried this :

`ManageLayout_GridView.Items.Add(abc);`

and i've got an error :

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify
>   elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead

Comment: It seems you need to import class by `using` keyword. At the beginning of your file try to add `using namespacetoobservablecollection`.

Comment: @erikscandola it's in the same namespace, do i still need to `using` it?

Comment: Maybe I don't undertand. Do you need to use  `scheduleDetailOC` in another class?

Comment: @erikscandola yes, in my **ManageLayout**

Comment: Ok, create `ObservableCollection<LibraryData> scheduleDetailOC` as static property and then in your `ManageLayout` you can use it in this way: `YourCalss.scheduleDetailOC`

Comment: Yay. Don't do this, don't create static proprty. You need just public property and inject your class to another by constructor injection or by property injection via [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: @VadimMartynov i actually tried the static property and not working. and im not sure how to do what you suggested to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store the reference to your collection in your class field/property. To have an access from another classes this property should be public.

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<LibraryData> ScheduleDetails { get; private set; }

    private void manageLayout_Click(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        scheduleDetail = assetListClass.GetScheduleDetail(xmlScheduleDetail);
        ScheduleDetails = new ObservableCollection<LibraryData>(scheduleDetail);
        ManageLayout manageLayoutWin = new ManageLayout();
        this.Close();
        manageLayoutWin.Show();
        manageLayoutWin.ManageLayout_GridView.ItemsSource = ScheduleDetails;
        ...
     }
}
```

Now you can manipulate collection by reference to the first class. You can use [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to save a refernce. If your second class needs to add elements to the first class the simplest way is to take a constructor argument:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private readonly FirstClass collectionHolder;

    public AnotherClass(FirstClass collectionHolder)
    {
        this.collectionHolder = collectionHolder;
    }

    public void AddElement()
    {
        var newElement = GetNewElement(); // creates element that will be add to the collection
        collectionHolder.ScheduleDetails.Add(newElement);
    }
}
```

It will works but not good because now `AnotherClass` knows all about `FirstClass` public interface. The other reason is that all classes that have reference to the `FirstClass` can manipulate public collection.

The good design is to create new interface for your `FirstClass` that will contains only allowed operations and use it in `AnotherClass`.

```
public interface IScheduleDetailsCollectionHolder
{
    void AddElement(LibraryData data);
}

public class FirstClass : IScheduleDetailsCollectionHolder
{
    private ObservableCollection<LibraryData> scheduleDetails;

    private void manageLayout_Click(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        scheduleDetail = assetListClass.GetScheduleDetail(xmlScheduleDetail);
        scheduleDetails = new ObservableCollection<LibraryData>(scheduleDetail);
        ManageLayout manageLayoutWin = new ManageLayout();
        this.Close();
        manageLayoutWin.Show();
        manageLayoutWin.ManageLayout_GridView.ItemsSource = scheduleDetails;
        ...
     }

     public void AddElement(LibraryData data)
     {
         scheduleDetails.Add(data);
     }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    private readonly IScheduleDetailsCollectionHolder collectionHolder;

    public AnotherClass(IScheduleDetailsCollectionHolder collectionHolder)
    {
        this.collectionHolder = collectionHolder;
    }

    public void AddElement()
    {
        var newElement = GetNewElement(); // creates element that will be add to the collection
        collectionHolder.AddElement(newElement);
    }
}
```

The other advice is to use [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) pattern and [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.100).aspx) that is standard de facto for WPF applications.

Comment: i'm sorry for the late reply, i'ev tried this and i have an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line : `collectionHolder.scheduleDetailOC.AddRange(newListElement);` i use this code in click event, but should be okay right? whats wrong with this?

Comment: i have two `public AnotherClass` one with the `InitializeComponent()` because if its not there, the code will error

Comment: I'm not sure about this exception without extra code. May be `scheduleDetailOC` at the moment when you trying to add element (because `manageLayout_Click` is not executed yet) or there is a reason why `collectionHolder` is null.
Yes, `InitializeComponent()` is necessary for user controls like page, window and other. But you still can pass `FirstClass` as a constructor parameter and store it as a class field.